# Sencha Touch Pull to Refresh not working after store is sorted

Tags: extjs, mobile, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-architect

I am using Ext.plugin.PullRefresh plugin to refresh the data in my list which is working till the list is sorted (I have three tabs which show the same data in different sorting-- distance , names etc).

After the store is sorted and I try to Pull the list to refresh, I get an error saying "Could not get data".

Any idea on what could be causing this ?

Comment: u should add some code and then anyone can get some idea..

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason for the problem. The sort parameters of the Store were being sent with the request which was causing a bad request. I had to remove the sortParam config from the Store proxy and that resolved the issue.